# Simple Firewall Program

Tags: visual-c++, firewall, packet-injection

I want to make a simple Firewall/Packet-Filter program for windows using Visual C++ 2010.  All I want to be able to do is see what websites my browsers go to and return custom text/HTML if I don't like the website.  I really can't find any tutorials on the web for this sort of thing, and I don't know the best method to achieve this.  Can anyone provide any info on how to make this simple thing?  Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

The [Windows Filtering Platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366510.aspx) is intended to support that kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to program/costomize a (primitive) proxy that has a custom handler for certain URIs. Of cause this would only affect browser you told to use that proxy.